# Null Pointer Exception with setOnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I sometimes get a null pointer exception with my code. Oddly enough, this does not happen every time, and I'm not sure why. Help?

```
package net.obviam.droidz;
public class HomeView extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



     setContentView(R.layout.menu);



    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
         page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View view) {
//                   Intent i = getIntent();
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DroidzActivity.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                 }

     });


}



protected void onDestroy() {
//      Log.d(TAG, "Destroying..");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
//      Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

The logcat says that the problem is with line 19, the setOnClickListener. I'm not sure what's wrong with it though. It doesn't appear to be referencing anything.

The Logcat reads like this:

```
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.obviam.droidz/net.obviam.droidz.HomeView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at net.obviam.droidz.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:19)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-17 16:52:13.816: E/AndroidRuntime(23756):    ... 11 more
```

And here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.obviam.droidz"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/images"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".HomeView" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DroidzActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

And here is the xml file that the button is found in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <Button android:text="Start Game!"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp">
    </Button>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That would mean that `page1` is null, so probably `findViewById` is failing to return a valid object.

Comment: Also, this problem only occurs when hitting the back key, or when trying to restart it after hitting the back key. Don't know if that's significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through the stack trace provided, I think the problem is when you start the new intent, you to pass the Activity's context, NOT the View's:

```
Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), DroidzActivity.class); // fix View.getContext() to getContext()
        startActivity(myIntent);    // change to startActivity
    }
});
```

As to why this is an intermitent problem, I have no idea.

Comment: That worked! However, now upon clicking the back button, the activity turns grey. Is this related, or do I need to implement something else entirely?

Comment: @kpeort Glad to help.  If you could accept the answer if it fixed your problem.  Why your Activity is turning grey, I have no idea.  Unless your overriding some animations in onCreate and onResume, and onPause, I have not heard of this.

Comment: @kpeort: You are using `startActivityForResult(...)` but your code for the HomeView `Activity`doesn't show an `onActivityResult(...)` code block. If you don't implement that method then you can't expect any sensible behaviour. Also if your `DroidzActivity` doesn't return a result at the point you click the BACK button (e.g., in its `onPause()` method), again you can't expect sensible behaviour. Fix both of those aspects and see what happens.

Comment: @MisterSquonk  Good catch, I had over looked the startActivityForResult, updated my answer.

Comment: Figured out the grey screen problem- the activity DroidzActivity is in landscape mode, so when I would hit the back button, it was still in landscape. I'll need to work out some xml bugs, but I'm on the right path now. Thank you both very much!

Comment: Sorry, still having problems with this though. Upon a screen orientation change, the screen just goes all gray, as if it is one large button. It is clickable (it turns blue on press), but it does not cause anything else to happen. This is probably a dumb question, but do you know what's going on?

Comment: This is something I would have to see in action.  What you could do in the mean time is lock each activity to what ever orientation you want.  Might not be the best long term solution though.

Comment: I tried doing that as well, the problem is that the desired orientation is horizontal, which is the one that is causing the problem.

Comment: @kpeort  This sounds like a different issue completely.  It might be best to start a new thread, and include your main.xml and possibly some screen shots to show what is going on.  Its kind of hard to get the big picture in the comment thread here.